# Is there a way to capture errors while loading required resources on Tampermonkey?

Tags: tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I have a tampermonkey script with a @require annotation for a library that provides me with certain tools for the script to work in a specific manner.

However, there are times in which this library is not available (it falls behind a login, so if no session is found, the @require returns a plain html with "unauthorized" explanation).

My objective would be to be able to capture if the resource is successfully loaded, and if it isn't provide with a handled error, which I'm not unable to do - I'm just getting the browser complaint about receiving a < symbol unexpectedly (because of the plain html resulting of the @require).

Do you have any ideas of how to tackle this problem? I've checked Tampermonkey documentation, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use `GM.xmlHttpRequest` to load the source from the url.
Then check `responseText` of the result for the "unauthorized" text and then `eval()` or `Function()` to execute the code, see [MDN for the difference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) between these two. You can do this every time the script is executed or you can cache the responseText with GM.getValue/GM.setValue

```js
GM.xmlHttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://www.example.com/yourlibrary.js",
  onload: function (response) {
    if (!response.responseText.startsWith('unauthorized string')) {
      window.eval(response.responseText)
      main()
    } else {
      // ask for login
    }
  },
  onerror: function () {
    // ask for login
  }
})

function main () {
  // ... you userscript ...
}
```